# Mongodb update throws invalid BSON field name

Tags: java, mongodb

I use following code to update a document in mongodb.

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
searchQuery.append("_id",new ObjectId("133443acb"));

BasicDBObject updateData = new BasicDBObject();
updateData.append("name","0.4");

BasicDBObject setData = new BasicDBObject();
setData.append("$set",updateData);

collection.updateOne(searchQuery,updateData)
```

It throws

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid BSON field name name

But I have a valid field name "name". Below is the data that is printed on getting that object.

```
{
    "_id": {
        "timestamp": 1517210676,
        "machineIdentifier": 2434039,
        "processIdentifier": 12248,
        "counter": 4509198,
        "time": 1517210676000,
        "date": 1517210676000,
        "timeSecond": 1517210676
    },
    "instanceId": "/device/5a6ec9932523f71d08079cef/port/5a6ecc342523f72fd844ce0e",
    "modelId": "/device/port",
    "ip": "192.168.1.6",
    **"name": "0.2",**
    "type": "ethernet"
}
```

I need help in finding the issue? Am I using right API's?. Am i using correct way to update a field in the existing document?

Comment: Try `collection.updateOne(searchQuery,setData)`

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i am using collection.updateOne(searchQuery,setData). error is thrown on using  collection.updateOne(searchQuery,setData) also.

Comment: Np. I can't reproduce the error with `collection.updateOne(searchQuery,setData)` now.